# Actionbar background is not being changed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have tried with the following code to change the background of the actionbar. It works with 4.3 but not below 4.3. With the following code,  null background is being set ie. old background is removed but new background is not being set. 
Please help me.

```
    public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing);
    }

    /**
     * Callback when button is clicked to change background
     * @param v
     */
    public void onStartClicked(View v) {
        int Min = 0;
        int Max = 2;

        //Random number generator between 0 and 2 inclusive
        int pos = Min + (int) (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

        if (pos == 0) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.inbox_header));

        } else if (pos == 2) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outbox_header));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to write this line - Drawable tmp =  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outbox_header) and debug it. Is tmp null?

Comment: Are you using BitmapDrawable as a background?

Comment: It is working fine in my S3 (Android  4.1.2)

Comment: Thank you.. I checked it but it is not null.

Comment: @gunar no it is just Drawable.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and checked the condition's execution flow ?

Comment: @SemyonDanilov do it with styles I did the same

Comment: Do you use ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: no. The app is supposed to work with 4.1+. So, no ABS

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally,I found the solution. It was acheived by showing and hiding the title of action bar after setting background.

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.inbox_header)); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Thank you all for your concern.

Comment: The solution Arun provides is cleaner. You're doing two actions that involve invalidating the actionbar.

Comment: I had already tried invalidating option menu. It didn't work for me.

Comment: Invalidating didn't work for me wither, although not pretty this works. Thanks

Comment: This issue happens only on Jelly bean devices, i.e. 4.1.x. This work around works, thanks

Comment: This is a fix for using SearchView as well and can be placed in onQueryTextSubmit and onSuggestionClick. I was running into this issue on 4.2; it appears fixed in 4.3 and 4.4.

Comment: @Dipendra .getDrawable is now deprecated. What should I use for android studio 1.3.1?

Answer (score 2):

The only think that you can do is to call  `invalidateOptionsMenu ()` after setting  background  for actionbar..

```
 public void onStartClicked(View v) {
        int Min = 0;
        int Max = 2;

        //Random number generator between 0 and 2 inclusive
        int pos = Min + (int) (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

        if (pos == 0) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));
        } else if (pos == 1) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.inbox_header));

        } else if (pos == 2) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.outbox_header));

        }
       invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me "invalidateOptionsMenu()"!